# ptr*** not working

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

The code is not working properly (segfault) when it has to access the foo elements through c.foos in the second for loop in main.

It only displays the fist element correctly, then at i=1 it shows garbage, and at i=2 it finally crashes.

So I guess it has to do with pointer maths.

How to do it correctly? The data structures are not allowed to change (no, it's not a homework, it's an oversimplified POC of [this](http://lxr.php.net/opengrok/xref/PHP_TRUNK/Zend/zend_API.h#43) data structure).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct _foo {
    int i;
} foo;

typedef struct _foo_container {
    foo ***foos;
} container;

foo** init_foos(void) {
    foo** f;
    int i;

    f = malloc(sizeof(foo*)*3);

    for(i=0; i < 3; i++) {
        f[i] = malloc(sizeof(foo));
        f[i]->i = i*11+1;
    }
    return f;
}

int main(void) {
    container c;
    foo **foos;

    foos = init_foos();

    c.foos = &foos;
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%d %d\n", i, foos[i]->i);
    }
    for(i=0; i < 3; i++) {
        printf("%d %d\n", i, (**c.foos[i]).i);
    }
    //memory leaks, I know

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note: this code seemed to work. I guess something has happened since the last gcc upgrade too, though I may still be doing something wrong.

**Addendum**: sorry everyone for missing the `*3`, I wrote this POC in a hurry. The actual code DOES allocated the number of needed pointers, via php's `safe_emalloc()`.

Comment: s/this code used to work/this code *seemed* to work once/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
printf("%d %d\n", i, (*(*c.foos)[i]).i);
```

I think the problem is about operators [precedence](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm). "[]" is evaluated before "*" if you don't parentesize your expression.

Comment: Even if this fixed the error you were seeing, it looks like you still have another bug that you should also fix.

Comment: Yeah that bug is not in the actual code, I've just written this POC in a hurry. I am using php's safe_emalloc(), which also takes as parameter nmemb.

Answer (score 2):

In `init_foo` you have to allocate `3 * sizeof(foo *)`.

Answer (score 1):

I think your problem is here:

```
f = malloc(sizeof(foo*));
```

It looks like what you want is an array of foo pointers, but you only allocate a single foo pointer.

Try changing it to this:

```
f = malloc(sizeof(foo*) * 3);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
f = malloc(sizeof(foo*));
```

You're allocating a chunk of memory the size of a pointer to `foo`. But then immediately afterwards you index it as `f[i]` with `i` up to 2. So you're accessing memory you haven't allocated.